# I can't assign data to []map[string]interface{}

Tags: go, interface, slice, go-gorm

I want to prepare conditions data for gorm.

```
email := c.Query("email")
count := c.Query("count")

filters := []map[string]interface{}{
    {"email": email},
    {"count": count},
}
```

I can take the datas at c.Query() lines.

After process "filters" variable's assignment line, I see the values as empty on debug.

Comment: `[]map[string]interface{}` is a slice of maps of strings to interfaces. Each element in the slice is a map. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm actually trying assign data to filters variable.

Comment: Yeah, that much is clear. Is `filters` actually supposed to be a slice of maps? How is it used? How do you decide how many maps go in it, and which values go into which maps in the slice?

Comment: filters[0]["email"] = "a@a.com", filters[0]["count"] = 10

Comment: I'm going to determine how many maps and which values.

Comment: And what do you mean by "datas don't fill into variable"? What is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: When I debug, I see the values as empty at interface part. The values don't fill the variable.

Comment: @CemilÇelik can you print the values `email` and `count`. Because normally this should work as in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aPZgcaQnqbl). Please elaborate more with code in your question

Comment: I try to print email and count. There is no problem. I try playground now. You're right, working normally. Perhaps there is a problem on debug tool.

Comment: Are you using delve debug in vs

Comment: Yes I use delve debug.

Comment: Very very strange. It printed to the console. So datas has been assigned seamlessly since from the start. But it didn't commit at delve debug screen. Thank you so much @himanshu

Comment: Also thank you so much @Adrian

Answer (score 2):

You are making an slice of map[string]interface{}, when I suppose you want a map[string]interface{} (no slices), if that's the case you need something like this:

```
filters := map[string]interface{}{
    "email": email,
    "count": count,
}
```